# c++ Is there STL algorithm to check if the range is strictly sorted?

Tags: c++, stl

By "strictly" I mean "without equivalent elements".

```
is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<>())
```

doesn't meet my goal because it returns true for ranges like `1,2,2,4,5`.

```
is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less_equal<>())
```

would work according to the implementation given [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until), but unfortunately `is_sorted` requires `Compare` predicate to be strict ordering (`Compare(a,a)` must be false), and `std::less_equal` certainly isn't.

So should I write my own loop for this purpose?

Comment: To be fair, it doesn't really seem a daunting task.

Comment: Maybe [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) ?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: `std::adjacent_find` with `std::greater_equal` should do the trick - it will find the first element that is greater or equal than the next one; if such element exists, the sequence is not strictly decreasing. Nice one @Rob, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting the comment stream:

> [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) with [`std::greater_equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_equal) should do the trick - it will find the first element that is greater or equal than the next one; if no such element exists, the sequence is strictly increasing.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{0, 1, 2, 3, 40, 41};

    auto i2 = std::adjacent_find(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::greater_equal<int>());
    if (i2 == v1.end()) {
        std::cout << "The entire vector is sorted in strictly ascending order\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "The vector is not sorted\n";
    }
}
```

<sup>Example derived from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find</sup>

Comment: thanks! Just change "if such element exists" to "if no such element exists" or change to "the sequence is not strictly increasing".

Comment: Oops. Is it better now?

Answer (score 3):

You can also make use of unique. It will return end of list if vector is unique.

```
bool is_strict_sorted(vector <int> a) {
    return is_sorted(a.begin(), a.end()) && unique(a.begin(), a.end()) == a.end();
}
```

Comment: Warning: std::unique modifies the original array you pass to it.